# Get a list of directories or files I don't have permission to read

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a directory, `X`, which contains many subdirectories (millions of them), which contain files. I have read access to some, but not all, directories and files contained therein.

I need to compile a list of directories and files under `X` which I *don't* have permission to read.

How could I go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that with this simple `find` command :

```
find . ! -readable
```

Pay attention to use it as your user and not as root or all files would appear as readable...